# How to protect from tampering of query string?

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

I have a query string like "http://project/page1.aspx?userID=5". The operation won't be performed, if the 'userID' parameter changed manually. How it is possible?

Comment: Just to kind of clarify - I'm guessing in your scenario you've already served the page out; someone clicked on a button somewhere else and got to the page "http://project/page1.aspx?userID=5".  


And now on this page they're going to type some values and you don't want them to swap that 5 in the address bar for a 7, hit "save" and have your website go and updating user 7's information, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hii all, thank you for your assistance... and i got some difference sort of solution from some other sites. i don't know that the best solution. that is to encode the value using an encryption and decryption algorithm... The sample code has been written like this...

```
<a href='Page1.aspx?UserID=<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TamperProofStringEncode("5","F44fggjj")) %>'>
        Click Here</a> <!--Created one anchor tag and call the function for TamperProofStringEncode-->
```

---

```
    
 private string TamperProofStringEncode(string value, string key)
 {
            System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES mac3des = new    System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES();
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)) + "-" + Convert.ToBase64String(mac3des.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)));
        }
```

---

In the page load of 'Page1' call the decode algorithm to decode the query string

```
try
        {
            string DataString = TamperProofStringDecode(Request.QueryString["UserID"], "F44fggjj");
            Response.Write(DataString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

---

```
private string TamperProofStringDecode(string value, string key)
    {
        string dataValue = "";
        string calcHash = "";
        string storedHash = "";

        System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES mac3des = new System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES();
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

        try
        {
            dataValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value.Split('-')[0]));
            storedHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value.Split('-')[1]));
            calcHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mac3des.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataValue)));

            if (storedHash != calcHash)
            {
                //'Data was corrupted
                throw new ArgumentException("Hash value does not match");
                //  'This error is immediately caught below

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid TamperProofString");
        }

        return dataValue;

    }
```

Comment: I still think you might get away with using the session. But if you for some reason rally absolutely **need** to do this via the query string and are willing to go that path it will probably work that way. I would still have a foul smell in my mouth though. It still depends... **Why** do you want this or **what exactly** do you want to achieve? You might be on the wrong track...

Comment: My use is, I have sent a mail with the content of a link along with the user id. When i clicks on the link in the mail will navigate to the page then the page will show the details of the particular user

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a strange requirement. Are you trying to implement some sort of home-grown security? If it's so, you really shouldn't.

Anyway, one way you could do it would be to take the entire url `http://project/page1.aspx?userID=5` and calculate its [md5 sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx). Then you append the md5 sum to the final url, such as `http://project/page1.aspx?userID=5&checksum=YOURCALCULATEDMD5SUM`. Then in page1.aspx you will have to validate that the checksum parameter is correct.

However, this approach is quite naïve and it would not necesarily take very long for anyone to figure out the algorithm you have used. If they did they could "easily" change the userid and calculate an md5 sum themselves. A more robust approach would be one where the checksum was encrypted by a key that only you had access to. But again I have to question your motive for wanting to do this, because other security solutions exist that are much better.

Comment: Would this not be awfully close to what a session(token) does "for free" in ASP.NET? It does give the user a more or less random/meaningless Id (the session id/token) which is then used to identify corresponding (session) data. Am I wrong?

Comment: @scherand: Sort of...  In your case, the actual data would be stored server-side, while in this case the data (userID=5) is stored in the URL.  It can be bookmarked, won't cause problems if you have multiple pages opening at the same time, etc.

Comment: ...which brings up a good point.  If the users get access to that URL, then there is no way to later remove that access without implementing a login/permissions mechanism or changing the checksum algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option that I found incredibly useful for my requirements:

[4 Guys From Rolla - Passing Tamper-Proof QueryString Parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20210610035204/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/083105-1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Anything in the HTTP request (including URL, query string, cookies, ...) is under the control of the client and is easy to fake.

This is why it is important to whitelist valid content, because the client can arbitrarily add anything it likes in addition to what you you prompt to receive.

Comment: I think the OP is aware that (s)he cannot **prevent** the user from changing the query string. But - to some extent - (s)he might be able to **protect** the application from such an altered query string. And that is what I think the question is about. Just my two pence.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite is the following. It uses a HTTPmodule to transparently encode and decode the Querystring with the **explicit** purpose of preventing tamperring of the querystring.

http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/aspnet/qse.shtml

It is perfect when Session is not an option!

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell whether it has been changed manually.  If you use query strings then you hyave to make sure that it doesn't matter if it is changed.  e.g. if you are using it to show a user their account details, you need to check wether the selected user, is the current user and show an error message instead of user data if it is not.

Comment: I just want to add: ASP.NET has a session, store information on who is logged in there and check in your code if the logged in user is allowed to see the data

Comment: Sure you can. Hash or encrypt the query string using a shared secret key, include that hashed or encrypted value in the query string, and then recompute it and verify it matches before you use the query string.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is allowed to change record 5, but not record 7 for example, this has to be enforced server-side. To do this you need to be able to identify the user, by requiring a login, and giving them a unique session key that is stored in their browser cookie, or as another parameter in the url query string.

There are abundant packages/modules/libraries in man languages for dealing with authentication and sessions in a sensible way - roll you own at your own peril :)

Answer (score 0):

Well - it depends :)

One possibility is to put the `userID` into a session variable. So the user cannot see or edit the value.

If you have other means to detect if the value is **invalid** (i.e. does not exist or cannot be for that user (who you can identify through some other way) or the like) you might get away with validating the input yourself in code behind.

But as you probably know you cannot prevent the user changing the query string.