# How to stop user from changing querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

How do I protect the url from a user changing one of the param/value pairs?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809383/how-to-protect-from-tampering-of-query-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an HMAC hash of the querystring using a secure random key stored only on the server, then verify the hash on every request.

Comment: that doesn't prevent anyone from changing anything.  It only allows you to *detect* that someone changed something.

Comment: @John: After detecting it, you can stop immediately and return a blank page.  If the user can't get any good out of changing it, I would consider that as being unable to change it.

Comment: yes, but the question was how to stop a user from doing something.  You can detect it, you can recover from it, but there's no way to *prevent* it.

Comment: @John that's bad wording on my part.

Comment: @subt13 Glad to hear that, since the only way to actually stop them doing so entirely, would be to either mess up their machine or break their fingers ;)

Comment: It's important to understand that the very fact you even *have* this solution available means you *cant*. It's an important prncipal to understand that any input data can be changed, and thus you need to implement a strategy to protect against it (such as, as you suggest, a HMAC). But in doing something like this, you need to be very careful not to do it wrong. (This is not trivial).

Comment: Good solution to a problem which can't be stopped... Validation is the way forwards in the respect, as even by using POST you could change the vars being sent to the server. Another approach would be to store vars in the session, and then only your code can easily change the values.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

You need to validate them. You should make sure your page accepts only valid input for each of the parameters. "Valid" may mean many things, like "Does the user have access to view this" and so on.

Comment: Yes, you can.  See my answer.

Comment: no, you can't.  You can only detect it.  anyone can mess with the address bar.  and if you hide that, anyone can intercept and mess with it in the browser's developer tools, or by using a proxy.

Comment: @Slacks: You display a disappointing lack of understanding of your solution if you think that it means "you can". You strictly can't (otherwise, you don't have a webserver). Your approach is validation, like I said above.

Answer (score 2):

You could encrypt them or hash them and persist the real value cross request.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's by definition an external interface. If your system's security depends on this, you should re-think how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Protect it and prevent from changing are two different things.  You can't prevent them from changing it, but you can protect/verify.