# How best to scramble or otherwise hide get query string values in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, postback, redirect

I'm working in C# ASP.Net and I want to hide GET values so that users cannot tinker with them. I need this because I'm creating a mechanism to allow for redirecting a POST back to a GET request, to enable browser back button navigation.

My first thought was to stash values in Session, but that seems against best practices for Session use.

What I'm trying to do now is to encrypt the query string and then use the encrypted string in the GET request. The problem is that the encrypted string is extremely long (1000+ charters), when the decrypted string is only about 30 characters.

The encryption logic I took from the MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Is there a way I can do this to get a shorter encrypted string?

Or, is there just a better way to do this in general?

Comment: It sounds like your question is the result of a questionable solution to a different problem. Perhaps with some more details about what you're trying to accomplish with history/backbutton could yield a cleaner answer.

Comment: Who/what told you Session was the wrong place to do this?

Comment: I would seriously reconsider what you're doing.  If you are hiding query string values for user experience purposes, use ASP.NET MVC or don't care (somebody tinkering with the URL knows that they can get bad responses).  If you are doing it for security purposes, you are doing security wrong.  *As a question*: What is your ultimate goal here?  What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: If it's a get request (and you're only doing things a get request should be allowed to do), then why do you care if they tamper with it?

Comment: Duplicate.  This question has been asked many times (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910566/how-to-stop-user-from-changing-querystring)

Comment: If you use a form that simply POSTs back to the server and returns a response. When you use the browser back button, it asks if you want to re-POST the data. If instead, when the POST back has completed processing, you redirect to a GET request that displays the results of the POST you are free to use the back button without any harassment.

Comment: @Josh: Do you think it is impossible to tamper with POST data?  Also: What if the user hits the back button twice?

Comment: @Thomas My understanding of Session is that you should use it sparingly, as a best practice to conserve server resources. If you have data that is costly to request and/or create that will be needed across page requests, then it's appropriate. Otherwise a large application can quickly use up more server memory than is necessary and hinder performance.

Comment: @Travis It's not that POST data can't be tampered with but I want to avoid making it easy to access different page results based on GET values.

Comment: @Travis As far as hitting the back button twice, with a redirect to GET you will go back two pages. Just like normal browsing.

Comment: @Josh: But people who want to tamper with it are still going to be able to, so you're not really solving any problems, but you are creating some by not allowing people to copy and paste links.  And if you're doing it for user experience...that isn't how people interact with a web site.  And as far as hitting the back button twice, you'll go back to the POST page, since your browser saw **Start** `-user interaction->` **POST** `-redirect->` **GET** `-user interaction->` **End**. Hitting back twice lands you to **POST**, unless I misunderstand how you're doing it.

Comment: @Travis I'm not trying to solve all the different ways users can hack a page request. I'm just trying to mitigate the extremely easy tampering of changing GET values. There is no perfect security, but there are things you can do to make things less easily accessible. In regards to hitting the back button twice, if you are currently sitting on the page generated by the GET request and hit back, you are taken to the form page. As far as the server is concerned it's like hitting the form the first time, but in all modern browsers, the fields are automatically populated with the submitted values.

Comment: @Travis If the back button is hit twice from the page that was generated from the GET request, you will receive the page you saw before the page with the submitted form.

Comment: @Travis I think you may be thinking of a browser level redirection. I'm redirecting on the server side. I believe it uses an HTTP status code in the 300 range.

Comment: This sounds like a case of premature optimization.  Consider the following:  http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/backbuttonblues.html

Comment: @Josh: I see what you're saying about redirection now.  Using is for security is still pointless: anybody who wants to bypass the security need only download tamperdata or whatever works for their browser. So you would only be stopping people who didn't want to bypass security (who wouldn't be mucking with URLs in the first place). I don't see any benefits at the cost of the ability to copy and paste links, increased complication in development, two round trips for everything and probably many more.  But hey, it's your app.

Comment: @Travis Consider this scenario. I have a search mechanism that returns a list of users in a system. After selecting a user, a page with information about that user is displayed. It is a very natural reflex to hit the back button to return to the search page. Without a redirect to get they would be asked to repost the data instead of just landing back on the search page. The ID for the user is just an incremental number. If I didn't obfuscate the GET variables it would be easy to access any user's information. When you shouldn't be able to. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @Travis Any system can be hacked, but you should at least take steps to not make it easy. It's all a matter of how far you need to go in taking those steps.

Comment: @Josh: But for that scenario, wouldn't it be *better* to not use incremental IDs and do some authorization on page requests? It just seems like you're using obscurity as a crutch instead of actually solving the problem.  But like I said, it is your app, so you can decide the threat model and security whatsits.

Comment: The IDs are what the system uses and it's not in my power to change that. To not use the incremental IDs in the url would mean storing them on the server, to be retrieved on the round trip, and that would mean session and I was trying to avoid using session. Not only is over use of session bad for memory usage and performance, if the session timed out and the user had to re-login, they would not be redirected to where they were. For me this is about the user experience more than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the technique at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/security/encrypting-query-arguments.

It encrypts the query arguments and includes a checksum to make tampering difficult.

Comment: I have to take a closer look at this, but it looks like about the same thing I'm already doing.

Comment: I haven't looked at the lib you're using and don't know what it includes as far as making it tamper-resistance. However, I personally try and minimize using Session because it can start to hog resources on the server. Check out sites like Amazon.com, they have extremely long URLs when you're navagating the site. Those URLs appear to be encrypted also.

Comment: I agree, I think encryption is the way this should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it through a session, best way, even if this wasn't the purpose of a session at the very beginning.

Comment: I just try to be cautious about what I use session for. Each thing you place there goes into the server's memory and with a heavily used application, can hinder server performance.